# accessing $_POST array variables in php

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm able to access my $_POST array values, but can't seem to get the correct syntax for returning only the "data" part of the array. If I run `var_dump($_POST["attributes"]);`, I receive the following in the response callback(which is exactly what I expected):

```
string '{
    "device_maker" = unknown;
    "device_model" = Simulator;
    "first_visit" = "1387478168.109";
    "last_visit" = "1388358490.638";
    latitude = "37.78583526611328";
    locale = en;
    longitude = "-122.4064178466797";
    "opted_in" = 1;
    "opted_out" = 0;
    "os_platform" = "iPhone OS";
    "os_version" = "7.0.3";
    "this_visit" = "1387478168.109";
    "user_id" = 1;
}' (length=389)
```

If I try to access any one of the attributes separately, like `var_dump($_POST["attributes"]["device_model"]);`, all I get in return is `string '{' (length=1)`. I'm apparently missing a key idea on parsing this data. How do I parse "attributes" so I can place each one of the listed values into an insert statement(I've got that part ready to go once I get the data)? Granted, my php is very rusty. So I may be overlooking something obvious.

It's frustrating to see the data I need and not know how to correctly access it. So, any help is appreciated. Please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: How did that data get generated? You realize it's saying that is a STRING? It's not an array and you're trying to treat it as one.

Comment: $attributes = json_decode($_POST['attributes']); looks like a good starting point.

Comment: That's not JSON: http://ideone.com/hb6Gra

Comment: @Jessica yes, looking at it closer I was coming to that conclusion too. A bit slower than you though :)

Comment: I did want to verify it first but yeah, here's a good example of JSON: http://json.org/example  -- commas, not semi-colons and colons, not equals.

Comment: I know it's not json. I posed a question to the developer of the XHR module I'm using because it's supposed to be json. A look at his code in xhr.js, https://github.com/raulriera/XHR?source=c, will show you how he did it. I use the post() function passing in the required parameters. I can talk back and forth from app to server. As I said though, not sure how to parse the result into something I can use. I even have content type set to "application/json". Don't know why it's not json.

Comment: If I stringify the data object on the app side, I get console output like this: `[INFO] contentType: application/json
[INFO] xhr:send:data {"last_visit":1388363277.231,"first_visit":1387478168.109,"this_visit":1387478168.109,"latitude":37.78583526611328,"longitude":-122.40641784667969,"opted_out":0,"opted_in":1,"user_id":1,"locale":"en","device_maker":"unknown","device_model":"Simulator","os_platform":"iPhone OS","os_version":"7.0.3"}`, which makes sense. Immediately following this is the `xhr.send(data);` call which posts to my webserver.

Comment: After further discussion with the author, it appears his code wasn't designed to be used with the Backbone.js data model. He thinks that may be the issue, but he's not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the string being retrieved in your POST is not valid JSON. If you can't replace the values being sent to the server, you can always do a (dirty) workaround:

First, replace some characters to make it a valid json:

```
$jsonStr = str_replace('=', ':', $_POST["attributes"]);
$jsonStr = str_replace(';', ',', $jsonStr);
$jsonStr = str_replace(',}', '}', $jsonStr);
```

Then we can try to parse it using the json_decode function:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonStr);
```

Now you can access it as a regular associative array, e.g.:

```
echo $jsonArray['device_model'];
```

Comment: If I can't get the app to send proper json (no reason to think it shouldn't), then I may have to resort to something like this. I'll keep it in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you should really check it on the client side, there is no need for dirty-fixing if you can solve it otherwise.

Comment: Jimmy T, yes you're right! But without knowing if the structure changes on the client side, or if he can change the client to return proper JSON, there isn't much that can be done!

Comment: Bummer, just spoke with the module author. Even he can't explain what would be the cause. He says it works just fine on Ruby.

Comment: Did he mentioned anything it being valid JSON? It could be that it is working fine on ruby because they are using their own data representation instead of JSON.

Comment: That's possible. I don't know Ruby so I wouldn't have thought to ask. However, I switched to a plain stripped-down version of the xhr call and I get the same result. Is it possible that some config parameter in my apache server may have transformed the data? I feel like I hit a wall on this one.

Comment: I doubt that the server is changing your data, at least I never heard anything quite like that!

Comment: Well, after all that, I found the enemy -- and it was me! lol. I was using the REST api incorrectly (no big surprise). If anyone is interested and uses the Titanium SDK, here's the link to the sqlrest api I'm using now: https://github.com/viezel/napp.alloy.adapter.restsql

Answer (score -2):

What you show here looks like JSON encoded data - it's a single string so there is no $_POST["attributes"]["device_model"].

You can access the data embedded in the attributes variable by converting it from JSON:

```
$a_string='{
"device_maker" = unknown;
"device_model" = Simulator;
"first_visit" = "1387478168.109";
"last_visit" = "1388358490.638";
latitude = "37.78583526611328";
locale = en;
longitude = "-122.4064178466797";
"opted_in" = 1;
"opted_out" = 0;
"os_platform" = "iPhone OS";
"os_version" = "7.0.3";
"this_visit" = "1387478168.109";
"user_id" = 1;
}';
// or $astring=$_POST['attributes']
$data=json_decode($a_string);
print $data['device_model'];
```

....but you need to verify the origin of the data - if it' not JSON, then this will break at some point.

Comment: I don't believe that is JSON. http://ideone.com/hb6Gra  JSON would be `,` not `;` and `:` not `=`

Comment: latitude, locale and longitude do not have quotes, as well.

Comment: @Jessica: yes, it's late here. (in my defence if I were trying to parse this then I'd probably convert it to JSON).

Comment: @meiamsome: there's no implicit constraint which prevents you from representing a float as a quoted string in JSON - but as Jessica points out, this is not JSON. OTOH JSON does not allow character strings to be unquoted.

Comment: @symcbean The labels lack quotes, they should be `"latitude"` etc.